# When permission is given to user via publish app, it doesn't apply to the dataset if it resides in another workspace

Tags: powerbi

When permission is given to user via publish app, it doesn't apply read permissio to the dataset if the dataset resides in another workspace.

Example: Say dataset is in WorkspaceA. Report connecting to this dataset is in WorkspaceB. I create an app in workspaceB- in app permission tab I add user who can access the app.

This doesn't automatically give read permission to the dataset since it resides in a different workspace. I have to manually give read access to users via the 'manage permissions' on the dataset.

Also, the checkmarks like the Allow all users to connect to apps underlying dataset using build permission, allow users to make copy of reports, allow users to share app and apps underlying dataset using share permissions seem to have no effect. What is the reason for this?

Comment: In the tenant settings, is 'use datasets across workspaces' enabled?

Comment: It is not enabled. However this doesn't prevent me from using dataset from another workspace. Is there any reference article mentioning that the setting needs enabling?